# Facebook Login button: apply custom style

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i'm facing a strange problem by using new Facebook android sdk 4.
With older sdk version i was using:

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fb_button"
    style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
    android:layout_width="485dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
    fb:login_text="@string/login_with_facebook"
    fb:logout_text="Logout" />
```

FacebookLoginButton section of style.xml looks like

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_facebook</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

drawable/button_facebook contains png of a custom button shape.
Now whit old version of sdk everithing works well, but with new sdk something gone wrong. i obtain this:

[image]

as you can see, theres two facebook icon: the circled one is of facebook button, the second one (the big one) belongs to button_facebook drawable). There's a way to hide the circled icon?

Comment: create own button and set background image.. And then call facebook on click the button..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even i faced the same issue while i was working with fb login.... I fixed the issue by adding the following code....

```
    fbLoginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebook);
    fbLoginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
    fbLoginButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    fbLoginButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    fbLoginButton.setText("");
```

and here is my xml layout:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fbLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fb:login_text=""
            fb:logout_text=""
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT 1:**
Facebook might change the location of LoginButton class which is present inside its SDK so u might need to change the XML tag accordingly. In my case it was inside `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` double check it.

Comment: but you are using com.facebook.widget.LoginButton, i'm using com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Comment: it doesn't matter....  it denotes the location of the class LoginButton inside the facebookSDK.... i might have used an older version of fb... adding the java code will solve ur problem... i am 100% sure on it

Comment: Not anymore, the gradle build will fail becuase `login_text` and `logout_text` aren't defined anymore

Comment: @Sierisimo Any solution to that ?

Answer (score 20):

In the latest Facebook v4 API this is the correct answer:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    facebook:com_facebook_login_text="LOGIN"
    facebook:com_facebook_logout_text="LOGOUT"/>
```

Comment: @Mythul...thanks...but where did you find the documentation for this?

Comment: If I remember correctly it was somewhere hidden in their official documentation. I did spend 1-2 days to find it to be honest.

Comment: @Mythul...do u still have the link?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `android:drawableLeft="@null"` to get rid of the small `Facebook` icon

Comment: Why is facebook not changing android:drawableLeft to android:drawableSTART="@null". android:drawableLeft is deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/facebook_lay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook_button_bg">

    <com.lovetohave.love.ui.LoveTextView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/material_small"
        app:customFont="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf" />

    <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:id="@+id/fb_progress_view_cir"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cpd_strokeColor="#fff"
        app:cpd_strokeSize="1dp"
        app:pv_autostart="true"
        app:pv_circular="true"
        app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
        app:pv_progressStyle="@style/CircularProgress1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can design like textview or button .and add following code inside button click event.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SignIn.this, permissionNeeds);
```

**Then put following code in onCreate method to get profile info**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
                    .getToken();
            PrefUtil.saveData("accesstoken",
                    mAccessToken, SignIn.this);
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(org.json.JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {


                            } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters
                    .putString(
                            "fields",
                            "id,name,email,gender,birthday,first_name,last_name,location,picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i(TAG, "LoginManager FacebookCallback onCancel");
            mFbProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFacebookTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                showAlert();
                pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            mFbProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFacebookTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i(TAG, "LoginManager FacebookCallback onError");
            if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                    && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                showAlert();
                pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
            }
        }

        private void showAlert() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(SignIn.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    });
```