# Android, how to change the default facebook button

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-widget

I am using facebook login. I am trying to change the button, but it dont now work:
I want to make the height 100dp.

Login Page xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF">



        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
                   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#FFF"/>


            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/bt_skip_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Skip Login"
                android:onClick="autoLogin"
                android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:te

xtColor="#FFF"/>

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style :

```
 <style name="FacebookLoginButton">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">90dp</item>
    </style>
```

I want to look like this, but just to fill the width.

[image]

I have update my code, Still no change to the login bt

Comment: Do you only want to change the height or you also want to use your own custom button?

Comment: hi, I update my question with an image. yeah. the height and the width

Comment: this link will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771884/facebook-login-button-apply-custom-style

Comment: @VikramInext hi, I just tried it. didnt work. I will post my xml sample here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put custom Facebook button as per your requirement, best option is that you hide the Facebook Login button and Customize the native Android button and put it above the orignal Facebook Login button. Now on click of newly customized button call **loginbtn.performClick();**. By this way you can change the text of Button also.